# How to perform pairwise row difference in excel

Tags: excel

[image]
Given are the barriers B1 to B14

I have to find pairwise difference:

```
B1-B2
B1-B3
B1-B4
xx
B1-B14
```

And,so on

```
B2-B1
B2-B3
xx
B2-B14
X
X
X

B14-B1
B14-B2
xx
B14-B13
```

I tried selecting row, fixing the cell and dragging for some sets and it requires 14*7 steps. Is there any shortcut to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If one has the dynamic array formulas: `FILTER` and `SEQUENCE`

```
=FILTER("B"&INT(SEQUENCE(14^2,,0)/14)+1&"-B"&MOD(SEQUENCE(14^2,,0),14)+1,INT(SEQUENCE(14^2,,0)/14)<>MOD(SEQUENCE(14^2,,0),14))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

To do the values then use:

```
=FILTER(INDEX($C$1:$C$14,INT(SEQUENCE(14^2,,0)/14)+1)-INDEX($C$1:$C$14,MOD(SEQUENCE(14^2,,0),14)+1),INT(SEQUENCE(14^2,,0)/14)<>MOD(SEQUENCE(14^2,,0),14))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that OP actually wanted to do the subtraction from the screenshot.... kinda poorly asked though.

Comment: @BigBen I thought so too, but the highlighted cell is text not a formula and it refers to text in column A.  So I do not know.

Comment: @BigBen but I added the values.